# Count values for the corresponding masks in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a table1 with values and a table2 with masks. How to calculate (count) the number of values for the corresponding masks at the base level (SQL)?

```
Table1 (id, value)
1, man;
2, human;
3, green;
4, white;

Table2 (id, mask_value)
1, *man;
2, gr*n;
```

The first mask (⚹man) matches man and human - count 2
The second mask (gr⚹n) matches green - count 1
Counter total value 3

Answer (score 1):

you can change `*` to sql wild card '%' and then [compare without escaping](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html) `like escape ''` eg:

```
t=# select *
from ta
join tb on ta.value like translate(tb.mask_value,'*','%') escape ''
;
 id | value | id | mask_value
----+-------+----+------------
  1 | man   |  1 | *man
  2 | human |  1 | *man
  3 | green |  2 | gr*n
(3 rows)
```

accordingly count will be :

```
t=# select count(1)
from ta
join tb on ta.value like translate(tb.mask_value,'*','%') escape ''
;
 count
-------
     3
(1 row)
```